# Using the word main as an identifier

Tags: c

Can we use main as an identifier?

If yes what may be the scenarios?

Comment: Of course you can. Actually, you won't be able to make an executable run if you don't. It's not a reserved word or anything.

Comment: @JohnDee Do/Did you know the Queen of England by any chance? ;)

Answer (score 5):

Why not, provided you don't use it in the way `main()` is used, that is, as a function.

```
/* Error -- > */ int main() { return 1; } // Redefinition of main()

struct main{}; // ok

int main = 0 ; // error

int main(void) 
{       
    int main=0; // But has to be local.
    goto main;
    printf("Hello");
    main:
    printf("World");
}
```

Remember `main` is `NOT` a Keyword. But i guess we have not ran out of words, so why use it?

Answer (score 4):

Technically?  As a `static` or `auto` variable name inside any function, or as a `static` file-scope variable in any file other than the one containing `main()`.  It might also work as a `struct` or `union` tag, or as a `typedef` anywhere but the file containing `main()`.

Practically?  It's a good way to confuse yourself when you come back to the program a year later and wonder what idiot thought *that* was a good idea.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok folks, here's the $64,000 question: **why** would you want to do this? Planning to enter the obfuscated C contest, perhaps? Some unique approach to writing a quine? A test case for a lint-like program? It's certainly not something you'd want to do in a real program.